# StreamBuilder doesn't build the widgets when the home widget in the app starts. Needs hot restart to get all users from the firebase

Tags: stream, stream-builder

```
//Inside home.dart file 

Stream<List<Usern>> getAllUsers() async* {
var reference = firestore.collection("users").snapshots();
Usern user;
List<Usern> users = [];

reference.forEach((element) {
  element.docs.forEach((doc) {
    Map data = doc.data();
    user = Usern.fromJSON(data);

    users.add(user);
  });
});

yield users;
  } 
  //Stream Builder code

     StreamBuilder<List<Usern>>(
                stream: getAllUsers(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  List<Widget> children = [];
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final List data = snapshot.data;
                    data.forEach((element) {
                      children.add(
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            print("my id is:$myid");
                            createChatRoom(
                              myid,
                              element.id,
                            );
                          },
                          child: Container(
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 20.0,
                                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                          element.profilePicture),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    element.displayName.split(" ")[0],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )),
                        ),
                      );
                      print(element.displayName);
                    });
                    return Row(
                      children: children,
                    );
                  }
                  return Text("Loading");
                }),
```

> Whenever I use app from start the list of users doesn't appear in
> the row widget .As
> soon as I press hot restart when I am in home widget the list of users in row
> appears...Is there something wrong with my code that streambuilder is not working?
> Does streambuilder works only when you add data to the stream or does it also check
> previous datas and builds? I mean to say when user logs in the app and does
> nothing, I want all the users to be shown in the row widget just like in messenger
> app.....does streambuilder only builds itself when it finds that the data has been
> added to the stream?